# How to Calculate Aggregated Product Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, aggregate-functions, exp

I have a table with 2 column:

```
No.  Name    Serial
1    Tom       1
2    Bob       5
3    Don       3
4    Jim       6
```

I want to add a column whose a content is multiply Serial column like this:

```
No.  Name    Serial   Multiply
1    Tom       2         2
2    Bob       5         10
3    Don       3         30
4    Jim       6         180
```

How can i do that?

Comment: How exactly is the multiply column being calculated?

Comment: You should not store a calculated column in the database. Instead create a nested select statement to compute the value for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, this is a pain.  Most databases do not support a `product` aggregation function.  You can emulate it with logs and powers.  So, something like this might work:

```
select t.*,
       (select exp(sum(log(serial)))
        from table t2
        where t2.no <= t.no
       ) as cumeProduct
from table t;
```

Note that `log()` might be called `ln()` in some databases.  Also, this works for *positive* numbers.  There are variations to handle negative numbers and zeroes, but this complicates the answer (and the sample data is all positive).

Comment: @TommySayugo - no, you can refer to the *same* table multiple times in a query. When you do so, you should use *aliases* (`t`, `t2`) to indicate which instance of the table you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Creating the CLR aggregate isn't so bad. I whipped this up in about 5 minutes:

```
[Serializable]
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.Native)]
public struct Product
{
    private SqlDouble _p;
    public void Init()
    {
        this._p = new SqlDouble(1);
    }

    public void Accumulate(SqlDouble Value)
    {
        this._p *= Value;
    }

    public void Merge (Product Group)
    {
        this._p *= Group._p;
    }

    public SqlDouble Terminate ()
    {
        // Put your code here
        return _p;
    }
}
```

Once you've got that, you can use the techniques usually used for a running sum (i.e. a triangular join or a window definition that bounds the rows, depending on your version of sql).