# How to implement Oracle User-Defined Aggregate Functions in Java

Tags: java, oracle, aggregate-functions

As [Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/aggr_functions.htm#BEJBEBHE) says

> You can create a user-defined aggregate function by implementing a set
>   of routines collectively known as the ODCIAggregate routines. You can
>   implement these routines as methods within an object type, so the
>   implementation can be in any language that Oracle supports, PL/SQL, C,
>   C++ or **Java**.

There is no other info how to implement it. I have found example of implementing this in [C/C++](http://www.orafaq.com/node/791)

Anyone know how to accomplish this using Java? Any info would be great.

Comment: You need to look at the [Data Cartridge Developers Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e10765/introduction.htm#ADDCI110), particularly the chapters on "Implementing Data Cartridges in C, C++, and Java" and "User Defined Aggregate Functions Interface". Best of luck.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38217040/need-help-for-performing-below-calculation/38219279#38219279 There is an example of user defined aggregate funtion there.

Comment: Apparently the  Java implementation of aggregate function is not very common approach (based on the number and delay of answers). Anyway a solid example can be found [here](http://dbprism.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dbprism/odi/db/CreateAggregateFunction.sql?revision=1.1.1.1&view=markup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes a Java implementation of Oracle aggregate function is indeed possible.
The enabling trick is not to use a Java implementation of an  `ORACLE TYPE` 
but to *define a PL/SQL wrapper package* above the Java class and use *the 
PL/SQL functions* in the TYPE implementation.

Very simple implementation of a  `Hello World` Java based aggregate function follows - the aggregate function returns always a
string "Hello World".

The Java class makes nearly nothing only returns in the `ODCITerminate`  function the string "Hello World".

Any practical implementation on a Java based aggregate function will need to set up a context class and pass it to each iterate method.

**Java Class**

```
Create or Replace AND RESOLVE Java Source Named "JAggrFun" As
import java.math.BigDecimal;

class JAggrFun {
/*
Supporting Java class for dummy aggregate function
Implemented methods:
initiate   - dummy
iterate    - dummy
terminate  - return "Hello World"
merge (is not required)

*/
  final static BigDecimal SUCCESS = new BigDecimal(0);
  final static BigDecimal ERROR = new BigDecimal(1);

  static public BigDecimal ODCIInitialize(BigDecimal[] sctx) {

    return SUCCESS; 
  }

  static public BigDecimal ODCIIterate(BigDecimal ctx, String str) { 

     return SUCCESS;                                                                 
  } 

  static public BigDecimal ODCITerminate(BigDecimal ctx, String[] str) {

    str[0] = "Hello World";
    return SUCCESS;
  } 

}
/
```

**wrapper package of Java methods**

```
create or replace
PACKAGE JAggrFunPackage authid current_user AS
  FUNCTION ODCIInitialize(
                  ctx OUT NOCOPY NUMBER
                  ) RETURN NUMBER
                  AS LANGUAGE JAVA
    NAME 'JAggrFun.ODCIInitialize(
              java.math.BigDecimal[]) return java.math.BigDecimal';

  FUNCTION ODCIIterate(
                  ctx IN NUMBER,
                  str VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
                  AS LANGUAGE JAVA
    NAME 'JAggrFun.ODCIIterate(
              java.math.BigDecimal,
              java.lang.String) return java.math.BigDecimal';

  FUNCTION ODCITerminate(
                  ctx IN NUMBER,
                  str OUT VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
                  AS LANGUAGE JAVA
    NAME 'JAggrFun.ODCITerminate(
              java.math.BigDecimal,
              java.lang.String[]) return java.math.BigDecimal';

END JAggrFunPackage;
/
```

**Type**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TYPE JAggrFunPackageType authid current_user AS OBJECT
  (  
   jctx NUMBER, -- stored context;  not used in dummy implementation
   STATIC FUNCTION
        ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT NOCOPY JAggrFunPackageType )
        RETURN NUMBER,

   MEMBER FUNCTION
        ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT NOCOPY JAggrFunPackageType,
                             VALUE IN VARCHAR2 )
        RETURN NUMBER,

   MEMBER FUNCTION
        ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN JAggrFunPackageType,
                               returnValue OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2,
                               flags IN NUMBER)
        RETURN NUMBER, 

   MEMBER FUNCTION
        ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT NOCOPY JAggrFunPackageType,
                           ctx IN JAggrFunPackageType)
        RETURN NUMBER
);
/
```

**Aggregate Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION JAggr(input VARCHAR2 )
RETURN VARCHAR2
AGGREGATE USING JAggrFunPackageType;
/
```

**Type Body**

```
create or replace
type body JAggrFunPackageType  is
  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT NOCOPY JAggrFunPackageType)
  return number
  is
  begin
    sctx := JAggrFunPackageType( null );
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;

  member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT NOCOPY JAggrFunPackageType,
                                       value IN varchar2 )
  return number
  is
     status  NUMBER;
  begin
    if self.jctx is null then

      status := JAggrFunPackage.ODCIInitialize(self.jctx);
      if (status <> ODCIConst.Success) then
         return status;
      end if;
    end if;

    status := JAggrFunPackage.ODCIIterate(jctx,value);

    return status;
  end;

  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN JAggrFunPackageType,
                                         returnValue OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2,
                                         flags IN number)
  return number
  is
  begin

    return JAggrFunPackage.ODCITerminate(jctx, returnValue);
  end;

  member function  ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT NOCOPY JAggrFunPackageType,
                           ctx IN JAggrFunPackageType)
  return number
  is
  begin
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;
end;
/
```

**Test**

```
select JAggr(dummy) from dual;

JAGGR(DUMMY)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
-------------
Hello World
```