SQL multiply values for similar rows
I have a table



Name
Date start
Date end
Code
Value




Name1
12/11/2024
12/11/2024
A
0.5


Name1
12/11/2024
12/11/2024
B
0.6


Name1
12/11/2024
12/11/2024
C
0.7


Name1
12/11/2024
12/11/2024
D
0.7


Name2
12/11/2024
12/11/2024
A
0.6


Name2
12/11/2024
12/11/2024
B
0.3


Name3
12/11/2024
12/11/2024
A
0.2



What I need to do is to write a query that will return Value for:

same Name, Date start, Date end
only for the Names that have all 3 Codes, so A, B & C
the value will then be a multiplication of AxBxC

So expected result in this case is only one row as only Name1 has got all 3 codes (A,B,C) and the value is 0.5 x 0.6 x 0.7.



Name
Date start
Date end
Code
Value




Name1
12/11/2024
12/11/2024
X
0.21



I know I can do multiplication using exp(sum(log(x))) combined with over and partition by like this:
select name, date start, date end, id, exp(sum(log(value)) 
over(partition by name,date start, date end)) as val from test

but how do I make sure I calculate multiplication only for the records that have all 3 codes?
Note : There are other codes that will not be used for this calculation so considering only the number of codes will not work.

Show the DDL and what your tried, because stackoverflow.com is not a free code writing service.

what rdbms are you using Oracle, MySql, Sql Server ?

@BryanDellinger: "Answers to questions tagged with SQL (only) should use ISO/IEC standard SQL" ,  That why I cannot/shouldnot post my MySQL answer.

One approach is you can do group by with Having clause to check for the all three Code existence.
Second one is to use CTE one to group by and filter and second one to calculate the value. Another one is using self join but that might be too performance havey if there is too much data in table.

Please, note that log(value) works if and only if value > 0 - if only value <= 0, say value = -1 then log(value) will be some complex number

Your can use STRING_AGG to do this:
SELECT 
  Name,
  Date_start,
  Date_end,
  STRING_AGG(Code,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Code) as Code,
  EXP(SUM(LOG(Value))) as Value -- see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30746142/724039
FROM mytable
WHERE Code in ('A','B','C')
GROUP BY Name, Date_start, Date_end
HAVING STRING_AGG(Code,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Code) = 'A,B,C'
ORDER BY Name, Date_start, Date_end
;

results:



Name
Date_start
Date_end
Code
Value




Name1
2024-11-12
2024-11-12
A,B,C
0.21



see: DBFIDDLE
EDIT: When value can be negative you can do:
SELECT 
  Name,
  Date_start,
  Date_end,
  STRING_AGG(Code,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Code) as Code,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Value<0 THEN 1 END) as NegativeValues,
  EXP(SUM(LOG(ABS(Value))))*CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Value<0 THEN 1 END)%2=1 THEN -1 else 1 END as Value
FROM mytable
WHERE Code in ('A','B','C')
GROUP BY Name, Date_start, Date_end
HAVING STRING_AGG(Code,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Code) = 'A,B,C'
ORDER BY Name, Date_start, Date_end
;

see: DBFIDDLE

This doesn't multiply though!

Updated the answer to get the product, and not the sum.

It's OK if and only if all Value > 0, if only we have negative Value, say -1 we are in trouble, since log(-1) is a complex number

It is kinda funny there's no MUL aggregate method!

Updated for possible negative values.

The edited solution works with negative values, but it still fails with zeroes: Log(0) is an infinity and that's why Log(0) throws exception

@DmitryBychenko: May I invite you to add a solution for that?   It is possible, and should not be hard to implement, because when only 1 value is equal to 0, the product will also be 0.   (It's been too long since I did anything with math,  sorry for not seeing the log(0), and the log(negative value) )

BTW: A solution, that aslo deals with  log(0) can be  found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37037543/724039

@Luuk: Problems with Log (zero and negative arguments) is the very reason I've provided my solution:  if we have just 3 values to multiply, let's do it - A * B * C. In general case, I suggest implementing custom aggregate function.

@DmitryBychenko: when choices are limited (in this case 3), then your answer would work. When the cunt increases another solution is needed, but also already give on stackoverflow (see: Multiplication aggregate operator in SQL, and the links found in that Question/Answer)

Presuming that the code is unique on any (Name, Date start, Date end) tuple, grouping by name, start and end date and having a having clause that checks for the group number should work correctly as long as you also filter by the code being among the codes you are searching for:
select [Name], [Date start], [Date end], 'X' as Code, prod([Value])
from t
where Code in ('A', 'B', 'C')
group by [Name], [Date start], [Date end]
having count(DISTINCT Code ) = 3

If your scenario is more complicated, then you will need to provide more details.

The question clearly shows a row with 'D'

@MatBailie thanks for pointing that out. Added where Code in ('A', 'B', 'C') to the code

@LajosArpad having count(*) = 3 shouldn't it be having count(DISTINCT Code ) = 3 ? If you have A, A, B then your query will return the rows which is not what OP wants.

And by the way no backticks allowed on SQL Server. Use [ ] instead

@ErgestBasha thanks for the having suggestion, I edited the answer accordingly. As about replacing backticks with squared braces, if I would do that, it would be invalid for MySQL, for example. Do we know for sure that SQL Server is being used?

@LajosArpad . Do we know for sure that SQL Server is being used? ,no doubt because OP added the tag sql-server

@ErgestBasha thanks for pointing that out, it did not appear to me until I reloaded the page. Edited the answer.

I suggest expand single Value into 3 columns A, B and C (I'm going to do it manually with case; in general case we can do it with PIVOT command). Then we can easily aggregate the expanded:
with 
  /* Let's have explicit columns A, B, C ... */
  Expanded as (
    select Name,
           Date_Start,
           Date_End,
           case when Code = 'A' then Value else null end A,
           case when Code = 'B' then Value else null end B, 
           case when Code = 'C' then Value else null end C
      from MyTable)

    /* ... which we can easily aggregate and multiply */
    select Name,
           Date_Start,
           Date_End,
           'X' Code,
           Max(A) * Max(B) * Max(C) Value
      from Expanded
  group by Name,
           Date_Start,
           Date_End 
    having Max(A) is not null
       and Max(B) is not null
       and Max(C) is not null


You can Try this
SELECT a.Name,
        a.[Date start],
        a.[Date end],'X' as code,
        a.val as Value 
FROM (SELECT Name,
             [Date start],
             [Date end],
             GROUP_CONCAT(Code separator '') as code,EXP(SUM(LOG(Value))) as val
      GROUP BY Name
      ) as a
WHERE a.code ='ABC'


SEELCT ??  is that new SQL syntax ?

Also GROUP_CONCAT  does not exist in sql-server.

@Luuk SEELCT ?? is that new SQL syntax ? , don't you make typos ?

Such typos demonstrate untested answers. For example, this would return no results for the OP's sample data (because 'ABC' won't match 'ABCD' for Name1)

And the inner query has no FROM block

@MatBailie I disagree with the answer (clearly it is untested, it will fail executing on  because GROUP_CONCAT  isn't supported by SQL Server) and the first comment from Luuk , woud be better point that error out rather than joking about. I had the same typos on one of my answers, I was in a hurry didn't have time to test it

LOG(Value) can well be a problem when Value <= 0
